# Reordering columns in a large dataframe

Tags: r

Using the following example dataframe:

```
a <-  c(1:5)
b <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat", "Dog")
c <- c("Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog")
d <- c("Rabbit", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Rabbit")
e <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat")
f <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Cat")

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

I want to investigate how to reorder the columns WITHOUT having to type in all the column names, i.e., `df[,c("a","d","e","f","b","c")]`

How would I just say I want columns b and c AFTER column f? (only referencing the columns or range of columns that I want to move?).

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're just moving certain columns to the end, you can create a little helper-function like the following:

```
movetolast <- function(data, move) {
  data[c(setdiff(names(data), move), move)]
}

movetolast(df, c("b", "c"))
#   a      d      e      f      b      c
# 1 1 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Cat    Dog
# 2 2    Cat    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit
# 3 3    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit    Cat
# 4 4    Dog Rabbit Rabbit    Cat    Dog
# 5 5 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Dog    Dog
```

I would *not* recommend getting too into the habit of using column positions, especially not from a programmatic standpoint, since those positions might change.

---

#### "For fun" update

Here's an extended interpretation of the above function. It allows you to move columns to either the first or last position, or to be before or after another column.

```
moveMe <- function(data, tomove, where = "last", ba = NULL) {
  temp <- setdiff(names(data), tomove)
  x <- switch(
    where,
    first = data[c(tomove, temp)],
    last = data[c(temp, tomove)],
    before = {
      if (is.null(ba)) stop("must specify ba column")
      if (length(ba) > 1) stop("ba must be a single character string")
      data[append(temp, values = tomove, after = (match(ba, temp)-1))]
    },
    after = {
      if (is.null(ba)) stop("must specify ba column")
      if (length(ba) > 1) stop("ba must be a single character string")
      data[append(temp, values = tomove, after = (match(ba, temp)))]
    })
  x
}
```

Try it with the following.

```
moveMe(df, c("b", "c"))
moveMe(df, c("b", "c"), "first")
moveMe(df, c("b", "c"), "before", "e")
moveMe(df, c("b", "c"), "after", "e")
```

You'll need to adapt it to have some error checking--for instance, if you try to move columns "b" and "c" to "before c", you'll (obviously) get an error.

Comment: That's great @Ananda Mahto - it's exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.

Comment: @KT_1, I found [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12544888/1270695) and posted [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18420673/1270695). It's a lot more than what you're looking for, but I had fun writing the function, so I thought I'd share it!

Comment: nice, it looks like dplyr relocate could have been inspired by this :)

Answer (score 49):

To move specific columns to the beginning or end of a data.frame, use `select` from the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package and its `everything()` function.  In this example we are sending to the end:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(-b, -c, everything())

  a      d      e      f      b      c
1 1 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Cat    Dog
2 2    Cat    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit
3 3    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit    Cat
4 4    Dog Rabbit Rabbit    Cat    Dog
5 5 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Dog    Dog
```

Without the negation, the columns would be sent to the front.

Comment: This is a neat trick, but it breaks down if you need to reorder some columns to the beginning and others to the end. Also confusing (drop and then re-add with everything? unclear how to interpret)

Comment: Yes, if you want to reorder some columns to the beginning *and* others to the end, that requires two different `select()` lines.

Comment: Clarified with Hadley - the negative operator only works in the first position of select() https://www.github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2838 
 In this special behaviour, select() will call all the variables, remove those with negatives, and finally re-add the cancelled ones with everything(). Having negatives and then positives won't work because they will have already been called in the special behaviour.

Answer (score 16):

You can refer to columns by position. e.g.

```
df <- df[ ,c(1,4:6,2:3)]
> df
  a      d      e      f      b      c
1 1 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Cat    Dog
2 2    Cat    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit
3 3    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit    Cat
4 4    Dog Rabbit Rabbit    Cat    Dog
5 5 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Dog    Dog
```

Comment: This will give `a,f,b,c,d,e`.

Answer (score 9):

The package `dplyr` and the function `dplyr::relocate`, a new verb introduced in `dplyr 1.0.0`, does exactly what you are looking for with highly readable syntax.

`df %>% dplyr::relocate(b, c, .after = f)`

Answer (score 4):

To generalize the reshuffling of columns in any order using `dplyr`, for example, to reshuffle:

```
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

to

```
df[,c("a","d","e","f","b","c")]

df %>% select(a, d:f, b:c)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the subset function:

```
> df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
> df <- subset(df, select = c(a, d:f, b:c))
> df
  a      d      e      f      b      c
1 1 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Cat    Dog
2 2    Cat    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit
3 3    Dog    Dog    Dog Rabbit    Cat
4 4    Dog Rabbit Rabbit    Cat    Dog
5 5 Rabbit    Cat    Cat    Dog    Dog
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the previous function to use it for data.table usinf the function setcolorder of the package data.table.

```
moveMeDataTable <-function(data, tomove, where = "last", ba = NULL) {
  temp <- setdiff(names(data), tomove)
  x <- switch(
    where,
    first = setcolorder(data,c(tomove, temp)),
    last = setcolorder(data,c(temp, tomove)),
    before = {
      if (is.null(ba)) stop("must specify ba column")
      if (length(ba) > 1) stop("ba must be a single character string")
      order = append(temp, values = tomove, after = (match(ba, temp)-1))
      setcolorder(data,order)

    },
    after = {
      if (is.null(ba)) stop("must specify ba column")
      if (length(ba) > 1) stop("ba must be a single character string")
      order = append(temp, values = tomove, after = (match(ba, temp)))
      setcolorder(data,order)
    })
  x
}

DT <- data.table(A=sample(3, 10, TRUE),
                B=sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE), C=sample(10))
DT <- moveMeDataTable(DT, "C", "after", "A")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
df <- cbind( df[, -(2:3)], df[, 2:3] )
```