# Rearrange Variables in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r

If I have variables in a data frame in the following order

`date var1 var2 var3`

is there a way to rearrange the variables so that visually when I see the data using the `View(data)` or `fix(data)` command, I can see them rearranged in the following

`date var2 var3 var1`

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544888/is-there-an-equivalent-r-function-to-stata-order-command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `data.frame` named `df` with `names(df)` as `c('date', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3')`, you can reorder it to `c('date', 'V2', 'V3', 'V1')` using this:

```
df <- df[,c(1,3,4,2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your example I would probably go with @JBecker's answer, but I'd like to bring to your attention 'DataCombine' , a nice little package with all sorts of tools regarding data cleaning, combining etc. The function 'MoveFront' would do what you want.

```
require(DataCombine)
# using 'OldOrder' as the name of the original df
NewOrder <- MoveFront(OldOrder, c('date', 'V2', 'V3'))`
```

Comment: You may also check out [my post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544888/is-there-an-equivalent-r-function-to-stata-order-command) or [at my blog](http://news.mrdwab.com/2013/08/28/an-r-function-like-order-from-stata/) where I introduce a function called "`moveme`" that works nicely to help rearrange columns in a `data.frame`.